# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)n!}{n^n}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)n!}{n^n}$

Please let me know how you did it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with Stirling's approximation?

Comment: No, i am not familiar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $xy$ with $x+y$ fixed is maximized when $x=y$. Thus 
$$n!=(1\cdot n)(2\cdot(n-1))\cdots(\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor\cdot\lceil (n+1)/2\rceil)<\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n=\frac{(n+1)^n}{2^n}$$
and since
$$\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<e$$
we have
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{\sin(n)n!}{n^n}\right|<\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\sin(n)|(n+1)^n}{2^nn^n}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot e=e$$
thus the sum converges absolutely, so converges.